# AWS Cloudformation : How to loop over CommaDelimitedList to create IPSetReferenceStatements in WebACL Rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-waf

I'm trying to create a WebACL where I can provide a list of external providers as a CommaDelimitedList and loop over those values to create OrStatement with multiple IPSetReferenceStatement based on each provider. I have an IPSet for each provider already created but need to use those dynamically in the Statements. How do I go about doing this?
I want to achieve something like this.

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "WAF Configuration"

Parameters:
  Country:
    Type: String
  ExternalProvidersWhitelist:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Description: List of external providers to be whitelisted
  DefaultBehaviour:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: [ allow, block ]

Conditions:
  DefaultBehaviourAllow: !Equals [ !Ref DefaultBehaviour, allow ]

Resources:
  WebACL:
    Type: AWS::WAFv2::WebACL
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub '${Country}-WebACL-common'
      DefaultAction:
        Fn::If: [ DefaultBehaviourAllow, Allow: { }, Block: { } ]
      Scope: CLOUDFRONT
      VisibilityConfig:
        MetricName: !Sub '${Country}-WebACL-common'
        CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
        SampledRequestsEnabled: true
      Rules:
        - Name: !Sub '${Country}-WebACL-IPWhitelist'
          Action:
            Allow: { }
          Priority: 1
          VisibilityConfig:
            MetricName: !Sub '${Country}-WebACL-IPWhitelist-metric'
            CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
            SampledRequestsEnabled: true
          Statement:
            OrStatement:
              Statements:
              #TODO: Something like 
              #foreach provider in ExternalProvidersWhitelist:
              #  - IPSetReferenceStatement:
              #      Arn:
              #        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${Country}-${Provider}-Arn'
```

I tried to check whether a provider exists in the CommaDelimitedList using the following in the

```
Conditions:
  IsProviderAWhitelisted:
    Fn::Contains:
     - !Split [ ",", !Ref ExternalProvidersWhitelist ]
     - "ProviderA"
```

...and then use this condition in the !If block in the statement

```
          Statement:
            OrStatement:
              Statements:
                - IPSetReferenceStatement:
                    Arn:
                      Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${Country}-BaseWhitelist-Arn'
                - !If
                  - IsProviderAWhitelisted
                  - IPSetReferenceStatement:
                      Arn:
                        Fn::ImportValue: !Sub '${Country}-ProviderA-Arn'
                  - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

Not only did it not work because we can't use `Fn::Contains` in the `Conditions`, it would have been too much repetition for each provider.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own [CloudFormation macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html), as CloudFormation does not support iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I followed the docs and was able to write a Lambda, and create a AWS::CloudFormation::Macro with name 'IPSetRef-transform' and with that lambda as the function. When I try to use that macro in my template to generate the snippet using Fn::Transform: Name: IPSetRef-transform, I get the error saying, "No transform named AWS_ACCOUNTID::IPSetRef-transform found."
Trying to figure this out right now.

Comment: @ShashankGoyal You have to make new question with relevant code and error.